# java swing timer not going off

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer

I can't seem to get this timer to go off. the program compiles and from my understanding this should ping every 1000ms or 1 second and perform the lines in the actionPerformed{} function.

```
public void stringGeneration(String args[]){

        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                String fullIstring = java.lang.String.valueOf(injectString[0] + injectString[1] + injectString[2] + injectString[3] + injectString[4]);
                jLabel3.setText(fullIstring);
                System.out.println("output");
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();

        //Thread.sleep(500);
        }
```

Comment: The code works fine for me. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. Maybe your GUI isn't visible so the program terminates before the Timer fires.

Comment: i dont really understand how to use this SSCCE thing.. the GUI is visible and all the other functions i have going work fine. i have the stringGeneration function inside of the main class for the whole file.

Comment: Well now is a good time to learn about a SSCCE. I don't care about your "whole file". All you need to do is create a class that displays a JFrame and then starts a Timer. Its 10 lines of code. If you can't get your Timer working in this simple situation, then you won't be able to get it working in a more complex program. Make the effort to post a SSCCE. If you are invoking this method then the Timer should work. The problem is somewhere else in your code. That is why you create the SSCCE to prove to yourself that you understand the basics of using a Timer.

Comment: i would like to try to post an SSCCE but i have no idea where to begin with that. the website is less than informative about how one goes about. could you post the working code by any chance so i can compare it to mine? i am a beginner with java writing my first program on netbeans. i imagine the problem is related to whatever event is supposed to be triggering the timer to even start in the first place. its like the function isnt being touched but i dont know how to invoke it.

Comment: Do you know how to create the basic "HelloWorld" application? Everybody starts by learning this. So now instead of display a message your do 3 things. 1) create and make a JFrame visible. 2) Create your ActionListener. 3) Create and start the Timer. The code ou posted does the last 2 steps. So all you need to do is move that code to the main() method of a test class and then display a frame before that.

Comment: "i imagine the problem is related to whatever event is supposed to be triggering the timer to even start in the first place. its like the function isnt being touched but i dont know how to invoke it." Exactly! Somewhere in your program you need to invoke the stringGeneration() method. And don't know what your program is doing so I can't tell you where you need to add this code because we don't have enough information about your program.

Comment: thank you for the posts. i did start with the hello world which was overly simple. moving from that to implementing an actionlistener is where more knowledge is required. the main function just has "java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SamplesJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just gave you an example and not something to copy paste. But you can try this if you want to try as is. In your case the above example should look like:

```
class HeartBeatTask extends TimerTask {

        private int timerInterval;

        public HeartBeatTask(int timeInterval)
        {
            this.timerInterval = timeInterval;
        }

        public void run() 
        {
            String fullIstring = java.lang.String.valueOf(injectString[0] + injectString[1] + injectString[2] + injectString[3] + injectString[4]);
                        jLabel3.setText(fullIstring);
                        System.out.println("output");

        }

      }
```

Your method will then call the above class like this:

```
public void stringGeneration(String args[]){
     HeartBeatTask tt = new HeartBeatTask();
                t1.schedule(tt, 0, 1000 * 60 * 2);

            }
```

Comment: i am giving such code because you provided just one method. you actually dont need to have separate class for Timer your existing class can extend the TimerTask and overide the run method.

Comment: This is for a TimerTask. The poster is trying to get a Swing Timer working. You should NOT be updating the state of a Swing component in a TimerTask. See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Please update your previous answer with this clarification and delete this answer. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more.

Comment: **-1** for **still** suggesting a TimerTask in Swing, last chance to fix before downvoting ...

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would to a scheduled task in java:

import java.util.TimerTask;

class HeartBeatTask extends TimerTask
{

```
private int timerInterval;

public HeartBeatTask(int timeInterval)
{
    this.timerInterval = timeInterval;
}

public void run() 
{
    // Your  function call to schedule here

}
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.util.Timer t1 = new java.util.Timer();

        HeartBeatTask tt = new HeartBeatTask();
        t1.schedule(tt, 0, 1000 * 60 * 2);
        }

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: 1000 * 60 * 2 = 2 minutes :) forgot to mention that :) but you can always check the docs :P

Comment: This is a Swing related question and when using Swing you need to use a Swing Timer not an AWT Timer.

Comment: thanks but that still doesnt work. i put it in exactly except i had to change the public static void main to just public void main.

Comment: @jake "i had to change the public static void main to just public void main"  It seems clear you have no idea what you are doing.  It will not work to copy/paste scraps of code from all over the place in the hope that something will work.  I recommend you return to [the basics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) and go from there.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson totally agreed. I just gave the above sample to give an alternate way to go about scheduling the task

Comment: i do have virtually no idea what i am doing. thats why i am here to get an answer for the problem i have so far run into. im just going by the compilers errors and trying to fix it based on what it recommends.

Comment: *-1* for using a TimerTask in Swing